# Laravel, Confirm Mail without Login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

we have the following problem:
We send after a successfully Registration to all User a Mail confirmation Mail. But when they try to click on it, they need to be logged in. We would like that the user don't need to login. Which kind of adjustment do we need to do in our Code?

```
public function emailConfirmation()
{

    $token = request('token');
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        $checkToken = User::where('email','=',Auth::user()->email)
                      ->where('confirm_token','=',$token)->first();
        if($checkToken)
        {
            $updatestatus = User::where('email','=',Auth::user()->email)->update(['is_mail_confirmation' => '1']);
            $status = true;
            $messages = trans('profile.thankyou_message_confirm_mail');
        }    
        else
        {
            $status = false;
            $messages = trans('profile.token_not_match');
        }


    }
    else
    {
        $status = false;
        $messages = trans('profile.without_login_message_confirm_mail');
    }
    return view('main.confirm',compact('status','messages'));
}
```

Comment: If you want, since you know the user, just log them in as that user.

Comment: You told laravel that this route endpoint needs a valid user. Just don't require that for this endpoint.

Comment: If you're using L5.6 I strongly recommend using [signed route](https://laravel-news.com/signed-routes). And I would recommend against using `\Hash::make(id)` for generating the token (for security and performance reasons). Make the string random and save it to the database.

Comment: ill updated the code again, but still same issues, any suggestions how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Would suggest you to include the email too in the confirmation link ie. confirmation should be `example.com/confirm?token=PR1234&email=abc@gmail.com`

but that's not necessary if you `token` will be always unique so you can ignore the email check.

```
 $token = request('token');
 $email = request('email');

//if(Auth::check())
//{
    $checkToken = User::where('email','=', $email)
                  ->where('confirm_token','=',$token)->first();
    if($checkToken)
    {
        $updatestatus = User::where('email','=', $email)->update(['is_mail_confirmation' => '1']);
        $status = true;
        $messages = trans('profile.thankyou_message_confirm_mail');
    }    
    else
    {
        $status = false;
        $messages = trans('profile.token_not_match');
    }


//}
//else
//{
    //$status = false;
    //$messages = trans('profile.without_login_message_confirm_mail');
//}
```

As a side-note if you happen to support uncommon symbols like ! # $ % * + - in your system don't forget to urlencode() the email before you add it in the confirmation link.

Also as @Tarek suggested make sure this method doesn't touch  any auth middleware because the user isn't logged in.

Comment: I like this answer.  Also, make sure your route is NOT using any auth middleware before reaching this controller.

Answer (score 0):

You just need two things:

1. Don't check for authentication in your `emailConfirmation` action code.
2. In the controller that containing the `emailConfirmation` action make a `constructor` in which you will except `emailConfirmation` from authentication like the following:

.

```
public function __construct() {       
        $this->middleware(['auth'])->except('emailConfirmation');
  }
```